# Grouping by, applying a function, and inserting a new column with corresponding values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to calculate a weighted average for certain cohorts of users, but can't seem to take the output and form a new column with it.

I have tried groupby and apply function, but can't seem to transform it back into a new column

```
 df = pd.DataFrame('cohort_size': [10,15,20,25,20,15],
'retention' : [0.3,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.5],
'nth_interval' : [1,1,1,7,7,7])

df.groupby('nth_interval').apply(lambda x: np.average(x['retention'], weights=x['cohort_size']))
```

I get the output as a series, but what I really want is to take those individual weighted averages and put them back as a new column in the dataframe, where each column value corresponds to the nth_interval

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, are you looking for this?

```
df.merge(df.groupby('nth_interval').apply(lambda x: np.average(x['retention'],
                                                   weights=x['cohort_size']))
                                   .rename('wgted_avg').reset_index(), 
         on='nth_interval')
```

Output:

```
   cohort_size  retention  nth_interval  wgted_avg
0           10        0.3             1   0.311111
1           15        0.2             1   0.311111
2           20        0.4             1   0.311111
3           25        0.5             7   0.533333
4           20        0.6             7   0.533333
5           15        0.5             7   0.533333
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either do a merge:

```
df.merge(df.groupby('nth_interval')
           .apply(lambda x: np.average(x['retention'], weights=x['cohort_size']))
           .to_frame(name='average'),
         on='nth_interval')
```

or a map:

```
s = df.groupby('nth_interval')
               .apply(lambda x: np.average(x['retention'], weights=x['cohort_size']))

df['average'] = df['nth_interval'].map(s)
```

output:

```
   cohort_size  retention  nth_interval   average
0           10        0.3             1  0.311111
1           15        0.2             1  0.311111
2           20        0.4             1  0.311111
3           25        0.5             7  0.533333
4           20        0.6             7  0.533333
5           15        0.5             7  0.533333
```

Or you can also compute it manually:

```
df['average'] = (df['retention'].mul(df['cohort_size'])
                      .groupby(df['nth_interval'])
                      .transform('sum')
                      .div(df['cohort_size'].groupby(df['nth_interval'])
                                            .transform('sum'))
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save yourself a merge with transform. For large data you usually want to prevent that.

```
df['weighted_avg'] = df.groupby('nth_interval')['retention']
    .transform(lambda x: np.average(x, weights=df.loc[x.index, 'cohort_size']))
```

As for how .loc works. .loc is a way to get a subset of your data. You can give it a label, index, or boolean index. The first argument is for the rows, second for the columns. Here, I use the index of the group of the retention series to get the corresponding cohort_size. Basically I am calling `df.loc[[0, 1, 2], 'cohort_size']` and `df.loc[[3, 4, 5], 'cohort_size']`.